# Advising evil-forward-char seems to trigger advice twice

Tags: elisp, evil, advice

I am trying to update [annoying-arrows](https://github.com/magnars/annoying-arrows-mode.el) to work with evil-mode.

Annoying arrows is this minor-mode that complains when you use the same simple movement-command too many times in a row. (I have also updated it to open a buffer when it is triggered to make it super annoying.)

[Here](https://gist.github.com/endrebak/0e31a2c23fb5aac40e8f) is my attempt at getting `annoying-arrows` to work with evil-mode.

One problem I have is that when the advice is triggered for the functions `evil-forward-char` and `evil-previous-char`, the message is written twice in the buffer.

So instead of this: 
`Annoying! How about using left-word (<C-left>) instead of this-command: evil-backward-char??`

I get the following message:

`Annoying! How about using left-word (<C-left>) instead of this-command: evil-backward-chaAnnoying! How about using left-word (<C-left>) instead of this-command: evil-backward-char?r?`

Anybody have a clue why that might happen and if there is a workaround? Any debugging tips would be appreciated.

There is probably nothing wrong with [my code](https://gist.github.com/endrebak/0e31a2c23fb5aac40e8f) as it works for the regular emacs functions `next-line` and `previous-line`.

Ps. This issue might be related, but is above my current level of emacs understanding:
[Problem with defining advice for evil-delete](https://bitbucket.org/lyro/evil/issue/165/problem-with-defining-advice-for-evil)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For efficiency reason, `evil-forward-char` is called again after narrowing the buffer.

Not an ideal answer but I suggest to modify the logic to advice stock `forward-char` and check with `this-command-keys` if the user pressed the expected keys (in this case `l` key). This way your advice is agnostic of the layer on top of the raw emacs commands.